# Find the potential of a conservative force/ Line integrals

Tags: classical-mechanics, line-integrals

$$ \vec{F} = -k(x-y)^2\hat{x} + k(x-y)^2\hat{y} + Kz\hat{z}$$

1. Find the potential of $\vec{F}$.
2. A particle moves in straight lines from $(0,0,0)$ to$(D,D,0)$ then to $(D,D,D)$. Calculate the work done by $\vec{F}$ using the line integral.

In order to find the potential energy I used the method outlined in this video, [Vector Field Potential](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLAK2IsQ_Uo), however that method is for Vector Fields and I need to find the potential energy of a conservative force. It appears to only be the difference of a minus sign after you have calcualted the entire thing, is that correct?

I am completely unsure of the line integral in this case, and could use a general background of 3D line integrals.

Comment: A conservative force field **is** a vector field.

Comment: Asking for a “general background of 3D line integrals” is far too broad. Are you familiar with line integrals at all? The number of dimensions isn’t really relevant.

Comment: As far as the potential itself goes, there’s an infinite number of them differing by a constant. For force fields, it’s conventional to take the potential at either the origin or at infinity to be zero, which then determines that arbitrary constant of integration. Whether or not that results in a “difference of a minus sign” depends entirely on the force field.